# A challenge training autoencoders is non-convexity of the objective. Why?

Tags: neural-networks, autoencoders, recommender-system

[AutoRec: Autoencoders Meet Collaborative Filtering](https://users.cecs.anu.edu.au/%7Eakmenon/papers/autorec/autorec-paper.pdf) paper tells:

> "**A challenge training autoencoders is non-convexity of the objective.**"

Can someone explain and elaborate this statement?

Comment: Its basically saying that your error surface is not bowl shaped (making it easy to solve by gradient descent), and is instead likely to have local minima which you could get stuck in.
It applies generally to neural networks - the nonlinearity in the parameters makes optimisation difficult.

Comment: @seanv507 I believe you can make an answer from your comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its basically saying that your error surface is not bowl shaped (making it easy to solve by gradient descent), and is instead likely to have local minima which you could get stuck in. It applies generally to neural networks - the nonlinearity in the parameters makes optimisation difficult.